# Standard Picklist but with picklist value referencing to User object

Tags: picklist, dynamic

Please may i ask for tips on how to enable a picklist of standard object or a custom field in standard object with dynamic picklist value? I want the values to be referenced to users object for specific profiles/roles only....

I'm aware we can create field dependency as lookup but giving it in picklist is waht the users are looking for and i dont wish to create a VF page overriding the standard.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show different picklist values to different users ?

for example picklist values are A,b,c,d 
user 1 should be able to see only A,B and user 2 should be able to see A,B,C

this is what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, if i create a custom field for opportunity tab the picklist values would be pretty hard-coded but rather i want to show the user names from the object "user" belonging to specific role/profile